# Proper alignment of select boxes in a line

Tags: html, css

I need to put equal space between three select dropdown boxes (left aligned, center aligned and right aligned). [image]

I am using some pre-defined templets with the following CSS:

```
.view-display-id-page .views-widget-filter-tid {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.view-display-id-page .views-widget-filter-tid_1 {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.view-display-id-page .views-widget-filter-tid_2 {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
```

I am just wondering what else can I add to the CSS to make it work?

Comment: What does it look like right now?

Comment: I have attached the picture (2nd line).

Comment: Yes, I accepted one of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`margin:auto` won't work on a `float`. Add a specific `margin` to the center item:

```
.view-display-id-page .views-widget-filter-tid_1 {
  float:left; 
  margin: 0 5%;
  width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. First centre all the three elements and then add equal left nd right margin to the centre dropdown box

```
 <html>
<style type="text/css">
/** all the three elements are centred*/    
    .main
    {width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 200px auto 20px auto;}
 /** provide the necessar spacing you need**/   
    .centre{margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;}

    </style>


<body>
<form> 

    <div class="main">
   <select class="left">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
    <select class="centre">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
    <select class="right">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```